# How to get PaymentMethodNonce in Brain Tree API?

Tags: .net, braintree

I'm trying to do API Integration of Brain Tree using .NET.

Can anyone please say how to get the    **PaymentMethodNonce** value from Brain Tree?

I following the code as per their [Guide](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/ios+dotnet/reference/request/client-token/generate)

I'm able to get     **ClientToken**, using this client token how to get PaymentMethodNonce?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you are using .NET then please select language which you are using for your client side. In BrainTree we have multiple platform integration's.

Here I have done with Javascript.

Follow the js code mentioned in the guide, after passing the values to the javascript function you will get the nonce value.

```
    <form runat="server" id="checkout" method="post">
    <div>
        <div id="dropin">
            <input type="submit" id="btn" value="Pay" onclick="btn_Click" />
        </div>
        <asp:HiddenField ID="hdn" runat="server" Value="" />
    </div>
    </form>

<script src="https://js.braintreegateway.com/v2/braintree.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    bt();
    function bt() {

            braintree.setup(document.getElementById('hdn').value,
      'dropin', {
          container: 'dropin'
      });
    }
</script>
```

For this we have to pass the 'hdn'(client token value generated by Brain Tree) value from code behind.

```
        BraintreeGateway gateway = new BraintreeGateway();

        var clientToken = gateway.ClientToken.generate(
            new ClientTokenRequest
            {
                CustomerId = customerID,
            }
        );
        hdn.Value = clientToken.ToString();
```

Once we pass the client token value, a unique nonce value would get generated. We can get that nonce value in the code behind with the name 'payment_method_nonce'.

```
string nonce = string.Empty;
NameValueCollection nvc = Request.Form;
nonce = nvc["payment_method_nonce"];
```

Comment: For dot net we have to go only with Javascript, according to BT Docs. Even now they have removed such things from their docs, first take look on that!